# Замена виджетов в окне при нажатии радиокнопки

Tags: python, tkinter

Прошу помощи. задача простая но не могу понят в чем проблема нужно при переключении кнопок чтобы одни появились а другие спрятались.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Radiobutton, Checkbutton, Frame, Label

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Main Windows")

def get_position():
    enter_button = rbt.get()
    check_one = [tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Первий'),
                 tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Второй'),
                 tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Третий'),
                 tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Четвертый')]
    check_two = [tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Пять'),
                 tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Шесть'),
                 tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Семь'),
                 tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Восемь')]
    check_three = [tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Девять'),
                 tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Десять'),
                 tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Одиннадцать'),
                 tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Двенадцать')]
    if enter_button == 1:
        for i in check_one:
            i.pack()
    elif enter_button == 2:
        for i in check_two:
            i.pack()
    elif enter_button == 3:
        for i in check_one:
            i.pack_forget()

button_frame = Frame()
button_frame.pack(side='left')
rbt = tk.IntVar()

Radiobutton(button_frame, text='Інструкция № 1', width=25, height=3, indicatoron=0, value=1, variable=rbt, command=get_position).pack()
Radiobutton(button_frame, text='Інструкция № 2', width=25, height=3, indicatoron=0, value=2, variable=rbt, command=get_position).pack()
Radiobutton(button_frame, text='Інструкция № 3', width=25, height=3, indicatoron=0, value=3, variable=rbt, command=get_position).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Radiobutton, Checkbutton, Frame, Label

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Main Windows")

def get_position():
    for btn in sum(check_buttons, []):
        btn.pack_forget()
    enter_button = rbt.get()
    for btn in check_buttons[int(enter_button)]:
        btn.pack(anchor=tk.W)

button_frame = Frame()
button_frame.pack(side='left')
rbt = tk.IntVar()
rbt.set(-1)

check_buttons = [[tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Первий'),
                  tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Второй'),
                  tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Третий'),
                  tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Четвертый')],
                 [tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Пять'),
                  tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Шесть'),
                  tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Семь'),
                  tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Восемь')],
                 [tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Девять'),
                  tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Десять'),
                  tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Одиннадцать'),
                  tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Двенадцать')]]

Radiobutton(button_frame, text='Інструкция № 1', width=25, height=3, indicatoron=0, value=0, variable=rbt, command=get_position).pack()
Radiobutton(button_frame, text='Інструкция № 2', width=25, height=3, indicatoron=0, value=1, variable=rbt, command=get_position).pack()
Radiobutton(button_frame, text='Інструкция № 3', width=25, height=3, indicatoron=0, value=2, variable=rbt, command=get_position).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо GrAnd ты просто спас или спасла меня.